# Python - running a program increasingly faster

Tags: python, numpy, memory

I have this simple `python` code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

print a
```

If I run it over and over on `sublime text`, with `(cmd+B)` it prints the result `[1 2 3 4 5 6]` faster each time, like so (in sec):

```
 1st run: [Finished in 7.7s]
 2nd run: [Finished in 1.6s]
 3rd run: [Finished in 0.5s]
```

then it stabilizes at `0.5s`, which is pretty slow, for such a simple program.

so I tried to time it, and got the following results:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
0.00280284881592
[Finished in 7.4s]

[1 2 3 4 5 6]
0.00325489044189
[Finished in 2.0s]

[1 2 3 4 5 6]
0.000813961029053
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

testing further, I timed the code bypassing package import:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; 
print(a)
```

and got:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
0.000219106674194
[Finished in 1.4s]
```

and finally, with `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
a=1
```

I got:

```
1.2614569664
[Finished in 2.5s]
```

what is happening with computer memory so the program behaves like this?

Comment: I'd guess the first time is slow because you have to import numpy. Can you show us times for a few more runs?

Comment: @littleO  it then stabilizes at 0.5. but the weird thing is that  if I wait for, say, 10 minutes and repeat the operation three times in a row, it happens again, even though numpy has already been imported.

Comment: A related question is why it takes half a second to run such a simple program. It should take like less than a millisecond, I thought. Do you know why?

Comment: @littleO you are right, and no I dont know why. sometimes programs as simple as this one run as expected on my machine, in milliseconds, and sometimes they run THIS slow. truly a mistery to me.

Comment: What if you just run this program from the command line without using sublime text, and time it using timeit or something. Do you get sensible runtimes then?

Comment: @littleO good idea. check out the edit, please.

Comment: Any timing including `import` and/or I/O operations like`print` should be treated with care because you don't know if python needs to create the bytecode for the package or if anything intercepts/temporarly blocks the output for `print`. Especially if you use something like `sublime text` the actual editor could introduce some additional offset (starting a python kernel for example). Interesting would be to compare the timings to `a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; print(a)` and `import numpy; a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])` and a simple `a = 1` to get the individual components of the timing.

Comment: @MSeifert did your test. check it out

Comment: that's not exactly what I asked for. To split it into seperate parts you shouldn't: `print` when you use `numpy` (so you're still convoluting `numpy` and `print`) and the `a=1` part is missing as well (to see what overhead is introduced by sublime). Also did you wait some time before doing the `import numpy` part?

Comment: I see. check it now. I waited about a minute before doing the import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are 3 main questions in your post:

1. Why it runs faster each time?
2. Why it stabilizes at 0.5s? which is pretty slow, for such a simple program.
3. After 10 minutes and repeat the operation three times in a row, it happens again. Why?

#### Why it runs faster each time?

The reason is that OS will cache frequently used files from disk to RAM. And RAM access is much more fast than disk access. This is called [disk cache or page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache). After run python multiple times, the memory is **warm**, OS can load related files from fast RAM. To be more precise, it won't be faster each time continously. Instead, after two or three times, it reach the fastest.

#### Why it stabilizes at 0.5s?

The time after 'Finished in' given by sublime text includes 2 parts: one is the time used to start `python` itself, the other is time running script.

In your case, most time consists of time starting `python` and time importing numpy package. There are some cases in my machine. All the time is "stablized" time.

case 1:

```
import numpy as np
print(0)
```

[Finished in 0.7s]

case 2:

```
print(0)
```

[Finished in 0.2s]

case 3:

```
import datetime
print(0)
```

[Finished in 0.2s]

As shown above, starting python cost 0.2s, importing numpy cost 0.5s. I think numpy is so huge that importing is slow.

#### After 10 minutes and repeat the operation three times in a row, it happens again. Why?

Because disk cache will be adjusted dynamically according to latest access. After 10 minutes, the memory is taken by other programs in your computer. Memory **cools down**.